# How do i use pathauto to create a url alias for nodes' menu local tasks?

Tags: nodes, routes, path-aliases

The nodes are aliased automatically using the Pathauto module.  E.g., `node/448` is displayed as `aliased/path`.

Is it possible to alias `node/448/edit` to `aliased/path/edit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Sub-path URL Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) module will do this.

Comment: Thanks, that would work for node/nid/edit.  I didn't know such module existed so i failed to be more detailed in my question.  I have a custom menu local task for a certain node type.  E.g. events/state-fair is an alias for a node of type event.  It also has a custom local task for emailing attendees, but the resulting url is node/<nid>/email-attendees.  I tested that module and it didn't set it to events/state-fair/email-attendees.  The module's description doesn't mention that it works on custom sub paths so maybe i'm out of luck.

Comment: It your testing, did the standard node/edit path work?  The module should work with custom local-tasks.  For example, I've personally used it with organic groups (node/%node/broadcast), nodequeue (node/%node/nodequeue), and node clone (node/%node/clone).  If you're still stuck perhaps posting your hook_menu code will help.

Comment: ah no, it didn't actually even work with the standard node/nid/edit where the node path is aliased.  I'll investigate and updated this thread.

Comment: There's custom_url_rewrite pair of functions included in my settings.php from the Facebook module...i didn't see them because i was searching for the function name.  Took another look searching only for rewrite and found the culprit.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for the [SubPathAuto](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module. Just uncheck the `Skip administration paths from sub-path processing` option in `admin/config/search/path/subpaths.`

Delete existing aliases first `admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk` then go to `admin/config/search/path/update_bulk`, check all the options, and click `update.` If required clear cache.

However I realized that this method disables the overlay. But everything else works great.